# solution to detect radar wave reflection that usgooe to detect human presence through wall

Tags: rf

in the market there are products that generate RF frequency that can penetrate though wall/ concrete, by measuring the reflection of the RF, human presence behind the concrete / Wall can be detected.

One such example is 
https://www.xethru.com/x4m300-presence-sensor.html

I encountered a situation where in my unit (top unit with enclosed area) with walls and concrete, the unit below uses similar device to emit RF and from detect my presence and where about in the unit by interpreting the reflected RF.

I have tried using cheap device ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G4TBkpJi5Sc ) to detect the RF presence, and it does feedback positive of its presence. 
And so I tried to shield the invading RF using aluminium foil covering potential areas where the invading RF is.
The problem is there are many other RF signal that the CC308+ detects which is not the invading RF. So my attempt to completely block the invading RF is not effective.

I tried reporting this to the police, however, police will only take up the case when I can show evidence of what my allegation.

So I am searching for a solution to detect the exact frequency of this invading RF, and also be able to pinpoint where it is coming from.

Anguish build up as day in and day out of my whereabout in my unit is monitored and the unit below start making harrassment using different creative subtly means targeting at where I am in the unit.

So a solution is greatly appreciated to put an end to this privacy invasion.

Thank you very much

Comment: Numerous SDR (software defined radio) dongles exist to plug into a laptop, and give you basic spectrum analyser functionality over various bands, some meeting your 'not too costly' budget. These would allow detection of emitted signals in unexpected bands. Of course if you saw a signal in the WiFi band, that looked like WiFi, how could you tell that it was any different from a normal wireless access point. Regardless of that, it would be fun to buy one and play with it anyway.

Comment: @Neil_UK even worse, one can do radar with your normal access point's signals – if your reception is good enough, you can usually fully reconstruct the original waveform in the passive receiver, and correlate that with the different reflections you get. Basically: pulse compression, with the pulse shape being your Wifi OFDM frame :)

Comment: Could you provide a link to the device whose RF emissions you're trying to detect?

Comment: Look for applications using a number of broadband mobile antennas to perform triangulation.

Comment: @jonk has a good example. If you want a few easy-to-read papers on that topic (TDOA of cell phones), look for the string *TDOA* on this page: https://www.cel.kit.edu/english/publications.php

Comment: I have edited my original query with specific details of the situation I am encountering, hope to get a feasible solution in this forum, thank you.

Comment: Your new question makes less sense. What allegations? There's absolutely nothing to allege here. You've built a detector for *something*. Well, it detects *something*, great. How's that a crime??! Like, you say, you have a fire detector, and it beeps whenever the temperature rises above 20°C. Now you called the fire department and they said they'd only come when there's actually a fire.

Comment: To repeat: you have a cheap device that says "uh, there *might* be something here". That's not even close to a proof. I'd call it a very weak hint, and you've got absolutely nothing that indicates there's any privacy invasion here! There's *a signal that excites your cheap-ass devices that makes no guarantees but is sold towards people who are **looking** for cameras*. Really. That's like asking an umbrella salesman how the weather's going to be this week, and then really believing it's going to rain all day.

Comment: Before I purchase the CC308+, for almost half a year, whenever I move to one room in my unit, almost instantly, a loud bang can be heard from my unit below.  And when I leave that room and move to another room, few seconds later noise nuisance (different ways of generating the noise nuisance) can be heard in the room where I am.  And, complete quietness in other room that I am not in. This of course is done very carefully and subtly taking time of day into consideration.

Comment: After I bought the CC308+ detector, and install some shield using aluminium foil, CC308+ show the RF signal no longer exists, and the nuisance was off for a period of time.  However, RF generator can be repositioned to get pass the area covered by aluminium foil, so few days later, the nuisance resurface

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: no.

Long answer: of course there's detectors for specific types of radar. These mainly have military usage.

But: you can do radar with any waveform. I've been building OFDM radar systems with IEEE802.11-compatible waveforms (as in: Wifi) myself.

Also, if you want to do radar, you don't even have to be the one emitting the signal – bistatic radars use separate senders and transmitters, and passive radars use someone else's signal (popular: broadband signals such as digital TV, but I've seen this be demonstrated with GPS, and other signals, too).

So, there can be no such device, because you can physically only sense what someone else emits, not what someone else receives, and even moreso, you can't see what they're doing with the received signal, so you can't tell a pure Wifi device from a wifi device that also does radar.

Comment: @Jack: thanks. *Radards* was definitely an excellent word, but *Radars* simply is correct

Comment: I have edited my original query with more specific details, hope that this can help to find a feasible solution to my problem.  Thank you.